# Little Law's: Concurrency

Tags: concurrency, computer-science, cpu-architecture, blockingqueue

I had posted this question on a google forum but didn't get a definitive answer.

Can someone verify if my understanding of Little's law is correct in the context of locking. Suppose I have a system where I acquire a lock, do some work and release it. Further, suppose that doing some "work" takes no time.

```
λ = L/ W          ( λ = throughout, L=Average number of customer in a stable system, W=Average time spent in the system)
λ = 1/ W          (Since a lock will only allow one thread to execute)
λ = 1/10 micros   (Supposed average time taken to acquire the lock)
λ = 100,000 per second
```

Therefore, just by the act of using 1 lock, the throughput of my system is capped at 100,000 per second.

Is my reasoning correct?

Thanks

Comment: 100,000 per second throughput immediately follows from the suggestion that the time required to process lock/unlock is 10 us. No knowledge of Little's law is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your required granularity of locking you could have a different L.

Depending on the type of work you need done you might be able to use a different locking method. For example if you use a lockless queue to queue the work a worker thread could run far faster as it always has access to the data.